# Unity raycast distance incorrect for plane collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

I've got a ray cast being created from the 'yellow X' in the pictures below. It is detecting the collision hit, however the distance is way off (~ 21 instead of 7 etc) . The green X shows where the collision is taking place and hence how long the distance should be

[image]
[image]

The Line Renderer is being drawn from start point along the forward vector for the ray hit distance, so in the second picture you can see where I have a much smaller plane with better tessellation it works fine, but with a larger ground plane in the first picture it is way off. It also works fine with other objects in the scene like small boxes.

I have tried using a box collider which still has the same problem.

Any ideas?